# increasing a variable name by 1, on each loop

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Using JS Adding a table with 'rowNumber', everytime code goes round the loop, increase value by 1 and create a new variable 'Row_Num' + value of rowNumber, to keep it unique.

```
var rowNumber = 1;

for (var attributeIndex in table.attributes) {

    var Row_Num + rowNumber = table.insertRow(rowNumber);
    rowNumber += 1;
```

//this isnt working, how can I get the value of rowNumber and add it onto the end of the variable each time?

Comment: Why not use an array instead of independent suffixed variables?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: still a beginner, some help or a starting point, would be great?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Frédéric pointed out, when you want to store lots of variables together, the best way to do this is with an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

So you can change your code a little bit like this so that all your row objects are stored in the array `tableRows`:

```
var rowNumber = 0; // arrays start with index 0, not 1.
var tableRows = new Array(); // store the rows in here

for (var attributeIndex in table.attributes) {
    tableRows[rowNumber] = table.insertRow(rowNumber);
    rowNumber += 1;
}
```

Then when you want to get hold of a particular value, you just need to access it using the index.

```
// get the 2nd entry - at index 1
var someRow = tableRows[1];
```